# Is there a way I create a SQL view of multiple tables based on a query of the table schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL database where there are multiple tables maintained by other people which I would like to join up to create a view. The trouble is the number of tables keeps expanding! The columns and character lengths are the same.

I can get as far as creating a list of the tables by using

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Table%'.
```

At the moment I have a union all query like the below

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

but the table list keeps growing. Is there any I can create something to loop thought the tables? Something like

```
*SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Table%') UNION ALL*
```

I know that wouldn't work but I'm hoping there's some sort of trick to get to go all the way! This is on SQL Server 2012 if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic SQL in a stored procedure. Not a view.

Comment: Why are all those new tables created? Seems like an odd situation.

Comment: It's because everyone has their own pieces of work to do and I've said they can create as many tables as they like but they have to stick to the format i.e. 4 columns, same fields etc. Seemed easier to do that at the time then having me maintain it all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @s nvarchar(max);
set @s=''

select 
 @s=@s +'(select * from [' + s.name + '])'+
    case when ROW_NUMBER() over (order by s.name) != count(*) over () 
    then 
    ' UNION ALL ' 
    else 
    ''
    end
from
sys.tables as s
where s.name like 't%'

print @s;
```

There is a bit more to think about, you need to make sure the field counts are the same before hand also to be on the safe side, may be best to avoid select * and use field names that you require. This should produce the SQL statement to run in a stored proc as detailed in the comments.   Spend some time error trapping this and doing neccessary checks for continuity in the field names as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never heard of dynamic sql before so I once I realised that a combination of this and this (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149335/create-a-view-that-dynamically-unions-new-tables) did the job.